# Channel mean in Rmagick? What are those values?

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I have the following code which tries to find out standard deviation of GreyChannel of a picture:

```
images = Magick::ImageList.new('mypic.jpg')

images.each do |image|
  grey = image.quantize(number_colors=256, colorspace=Magick::GRAYColorspace)
  p grey.inspect # -> mypic.jpg JPEG 69x120 69x120+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit
  p "GREY CHANNEL DEPTH"
  p.grey.channel_depth(Magick::GrayChannel) # -> 16
  p.channel_mean(Magick::GrayChannel) # -> [26929.525603864735, 17142.094885263676]
end
```

My question is: Why are these values so big? `[26929.525603864735, 17142.094885263676]`

I mean, those are mean and standard deviation, but how would I convert them into the range of 0-1 ? Should I divide by 2^16 or 2^8? It's confusing because even though the pictures seems to be 8-bit, the channel depth is 16.

I have also notice that for another picture, the channel depth is 8, but the values of p.channel_mean are [35394.21133333333, 30093.66624626083]

Comment: Have you tried this with all #000, #fff, #888, ... images to see if there's any obvious relationship? Then back to the docs to see if there's any support for your empirical findings.

Comment: Yep. Tried with #000 and #fff in an 8 bit pic and the mean is 65535 and standard deviation is 0. So I am assuming that it doesn't care about the number of bits of the pic, but of the current ImageMagick isntalation which in my case is 16 bits..

Comment: Related: [php imagemagick statistics usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615938/php-imagemagick-statistics-usage/19620182)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image may be quantized down to eight bits but you're still working with ImageMagick's internal format. The depth of the internal format is in [`Magick::QuantumDepth`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/constants.html#Miscellaneous_constants):

> `QuantumDepth`
>   The number of bits in a quantum.

and AFAIK that's a compile-time constant for the underlying ImageMagick libraries. A QuantumDepth of 16 corresponds to a `Magick::QuantumRange` of 65535 (or `0 ... 2**16` or `0 .. (2**16 - 1)` if you prefer). A quick look at [`Magick::Pixel`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/struct.html#Pixel) might be a good starting point for tracing all this stuff out.

If you want your values to be inside the `[0, 1]` interval then scale them down using `Magick::QuantumRange`:

```
p.channel_mean(Magick::GrayChannel).map { |x| x / Magick::QuantumRange }
```